# Local time for report generation

Tags: python, django, date, windowsiot

I am working on a device that will be measuring certain data and creating pdf's based on this data. The device is running a Windows IOT core front end and django on the back end on a separate device. The two communicate using an api from the django server. The problem that I am currently generating the reports on the backend and sending them to the front end, and when i am taking the date when the data is collected to create the report it is always in UTC, which is expected. We need to be able to generate these reports in the users current timezone. The user can set the timezone of Windows IOT through a built in endpoint on the administration portal. The problem for the back end is that it is only accessible from the IOT interface so we need some way to set the timezone using the set timezone on the front end or at least pass the timezone to the function that is creating the report so we can convert the UTC datetime stamp to whatever the user has set. The big problem is that what is available for the Windows IOT is there are over 130 different entries for time zones and I cannot think of an easy way to convert these to a parseable timezone for the back end to comprehend. I would like to find some way to convert the data given from Windows IOT to create a report in the correct timezone.

This is part of the options for time zones from Windows IOT.

```
{'Description': '(UTC-09:30) Marquesas Islands', 'Index': 4, 'Name': 'Marquesas Standard Time'}
{'Description': '(UTC-09:00) Alaska', 'Index': 5, 'Name': 'Alaskan Standard Time'}
{'Description': '(UTC-09:00) Coordinated Universal Time-09', 'Index': 6, 'Name': 'UTC-09'}
{'Description': '(UTC-08:00) Baja California', 'Index': 7, 'Name': 'Pacific Standard Time (Mexico)'}
{'Description': '(UTC-08:00) Coordinated Universal Time-08', 'Index': 8, 'Name': 'UTC-08'}
```

Comment: Surely there's an API for getting the timezone offset too?

Comment: I mean I could do that but there are subtle differences between just a basic offset and the timezone. Two times that use the same offset do not always follow the same rules such as DST.

Comment: But wouldn't it be enough to store the local time and the offset at that time?

Comment: Django uses the `pytz` timezones: `import pytz; print(pytz.all_timezones)`. You just need to map all the Windows IOT timezone strings (the `Name` value) to the pytz timezones in a dictionary to then extract the correct timezone. And you should not let the user choose any of the "coordinated universal time"s.

Comment: @AKX the offset will change twice a year in a given time zone, if the time zone has DST. Just knowing the offset doesn't tell you if the user is in a DST zone or not.

Comment: @dirkgroten That is what i was thinking I had to do i just didn't want that but it seems to be the only option i have.

Comment: It is the only option, since your format doesn't seem to be a standard ISO format (which python uses). Hey, you only have to do it once :-)